# question about how do you think

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I don't know that "how do you think?" is wrong.

I'm not a native speaker, but people told me that a native speaker doesn't speak "how do you think?

I want to know why they do, and they usually say "what do you think?"

Is there any difference between them?

Comment: You say *I don't know that "how do you think?" is wrong*, but then you say people have told you it's wrong. Just believe them - native speakers *do not* normally ask *How do you think?* when they want to know someone's thoughts / opinions about something. But there's not really any clear-cut "reason" for this, because we can ask ***How** do you **see** it?* with exactly the same meaning as ***What** do you **think** about it?* You just have to learn that some constructions work with ***How...?*** and some work with ***What...?***

Answer (score 2):

The reason is simply that: A) "how" usually refers to the *mechanism* or *method* by which something is done, while "what" would more likely refer to the *content* of what is being done; and B) in most cases, a native speaker would be trying to convey the "what" form. In other words:

> What do you think?

means something like:

> Tell me what you are thinking -- i.e. the contents of your current thoughts.

whereas:

> How do you think?

means something like:

> Tell me about the brain mechanisms that result in you having any thoughts at all.

You can see that most people would only ever ask the first. The exception might be a neuroscientist, or maybe a psychiatrist.